# The closure of a balanced set is balanced

Tags: general-topology

It is defined that a set $A$ in a TVS is called balanced if $\lambda A\subset A $, where $\lambda$ is a number such that $|\lambda|\leq 1$. We need to show that the closure, $\overline A$, of $A$ is also balanced, that is, $\lambda  \overline A \subset\overline A$ . We know that $\lambda A\subset A \Rightarrow \overline{ \lambda A}\subset\overline A $. But we must show $\lambda\overline A=\overline{\lambda A}$. Any help is appricated.

Comment: Multiplication by $\lambda$ is an isomorphism of topological vector spaces (in particular, it is a homeomorphism). Does this clarify?

Comment: Thanks @ knsam: from your comment I understand this: Since the mapping defined by $T_\lambda(x)=\lambda x$ from $A$ to $\lambda A$ is homeomorphism, we have $ T_\lambda(A)=\lambda A$ and so $ T_\lambda(\overline A)=\lambda \overline A=\overline{\lambda A}$.Is it true?

Comment: Yes that's right. :)

Comment: You need $\lambda \neq 0$ of course, but then the balanced condition is trivially satisfied (we only need $A$ (and thus its closure) to include $0$ for that).